# postgres updated from 9.1 to 9.2, required database update fails

Tags: amazon-ec2, redhat, postgresql, yum

On going from postgres 9.1 to 9.2, it says that the data bases need to be upgraded so on giving the upgrade command I give and get the following

```
$ sudo service postgresql upgrade
Stopping postgresql service:                               [  OK  ]
Upgrading database:                                        [FAILED]
See /var/lib/pgsql9/pgupgrade.log for details.
```

The contents of the log file `/var/lib/pgsql9/pgupgrade.log` are

```
Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking current, bin, and data directories                 ok
Checking cluster versions                                   ok

connection to database failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied


could not connect to old postmaster started with the command:
"/usr/lib64/pgsql/postgresql-9.1/bin/pg_ctl" -w -l "pg_upgrade_server.log" -D "/var/lib/pgsql9/data-old" -o "-p 5432 -b  -c listen_addresses='' -c unix_socket_permissions=0700 -c unix_socket_directory='/var/lib/pgsql9'" start
Failure, exiting
```

I used the postgres with password enable something like this `pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=pgdbname user=postgres password=postgrespassword");`

I had `yum update`d my system and fell into this. Can you even suggest a way in which I can revert back everything then it will be great!

Comment: is the following file still there? `/usr/lib64/pgsql/postgresql-9.1/bin/pg_ctl`

Comment: What distro and version?  I'd guess CentOS, but it'd be nice not to have to guess!

Comment: @Mike Yes, it is there.

Comment: @MadHatter Sorry, I ll remember next time. It is basically EC2 instance (Amazon Linux AMI). So, RHEL

Comment: @rahulg Amazon Linux is **not** RHEL. Not even close. Their packaging for PostgreSQL is absolutely awful, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

### Workaround

Edit your `pg_hba.conf` and set connections on `local` to `trust` for the duration of the upgrade.

### Background

Amazon's Amazon Linux team have made the bizarre decision to do a major version upgrade of PostgreSQL on a simple "yum update". Most vendors use different package names for different major versions so users have to make the explicit decision to upgrade. [Amazon has not done so](http://people.planetpostgresql.org/andrew/index.php?/archives/297-Amazons-serious-PostgreSQL-packaging-blunder.html) and [do not take feedback about this issue seriously](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=397693).

Upgrading users to a new PostgreSQL version on "yum update" is the wrong thing to do for exactly the reason you've encountered: `pg_upgrade` has limitations, and you can't do a dump and reload unless you have the old server version's binaries around.

I [wrote a note about this a while ago](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28245/i-just-upgraded-postgresql-with-yum-on-amazon-linux-now-postgresql-wont-start).

The [Amazon Linux FAQ entry on this topic](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/faqs/#postgresql9) has improved since I wrote about it, but still doesn't acknowledge that they're creating the problem with their bad packaging policies.

Seriously consider using a distro that takes more care with packaging PostgreSQL. [The PGDG team](http://yum.postgresql.org/) isn't producing packages for Amazon Linux at this point, otherwise I'd recommend using them.